# Make Post Requests with Files Simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, http, post

I write a simple server and it runs well.
So I want to write some codes which will make many post requests to my server simultaneously to simulate a pressure test. I use python.

Suppose the url of my server is `http://myserver.com`.
`file1.jpg` and `file2.jpg` are the files needed to be uploaded to the server.
Here is my testing code. I use `threading` and `urllib2`.

**async_posts.py**

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
import urllib2, sys

num_thread = 4
queue = Queue(2*num_thread)
def make_post(url):
    register_openers()
    data = {"file1": open("path/to/file1.jpg"), "file2": open("path/to/file2.jpg")}
    datagen, headers = multipart_encode(data)
    request = urllib2.Request(url, datagen, headers)
    start = time.time()
    res = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    end = time.time()
    return res.code, end - start # Return the status code and duration of this request.

def deamon():
    while True:
        url = queue.get()
        status, duration = make_post(url)
        print status, duration
        queue.task_done()

for _ in range(num_thread):
    thd = Thread(target = daemon)
    thd.daemon = True
    thd.start()

try:
    urls = ["http://myserver.com"] * num_thread
    for url in urls:
        queue.put(url)
    queue.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)
```

When `num_thread` is small (ex: 4), my code runs smoothly. But as I switch `num_thread` to slightly larger number, say 10, all the threading things break down and keep throwing `httplib.BadStatusLine` error.

I don't know why my code goes wrong or maybe there is better way to do this?

A a reference, my server is written in python using `flask` and `gunicorn`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Twisted or asyncio would be a much better way to accomplish this. The threading module is rarely a good thing to use.

Comment: Ok, I think I will try Twisted. But I still wonder why things go wrong.